# google map not displayed upon signed released apk even after getting new key generated from sha1

Tags: android

I have an app which uses google map. But google map is not displayed when I install signed released apk and use. I have generated the SHA1 using keytool & using that SHA1, I have generated one google maps key.

Then I again compiled an release apk, but google map is still not displayed.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put it in your manifest like so? `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY"/>`

Comment: I am putting it like :    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

Comment: Yours should work, but google recommends the geo one. This is from their documentation: "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY is the recommended metadata name for the API key. A key with this name can be used to authenticate to multiple Google Maps-based APIs on the Android platform, including the Google Maps Android API. For backwards compatibility, the API also supports the name com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

Comment: Andrew :-)!!! It worked  man!!!! thank you so much :-)

Comment: It is happening due to you added debug 'SHA1' key on google(SHA-1 certificate fingerprint), So please create SHA1 for release mode and put it on google(SHA-1 certificate fingerprint), for more info Kindly have a look on this video **How to create SHA1 for release https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g75cZXjmuj8&feature=youtu.be**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been through the same. After days of struggle and research here is my code. My requirement was opening a map in fragment and the pointing to a certain location. Put a marker on the new location. now On click in the title it should open up a new map with the updated location. so what i did is that just copied the latitude,longitude value and passed it to the new activity with an intent... :) Try it!!
 Tell me if you face any problem in implementing it...I will try helping you out..

https://technophilecoders.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/how-to-add-google-mapping-to-an-android-application/

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps to get Release **SHA1**

1. Find your .jks path which is used while creating signed apk.

   **Ex:** `/Users/dharm/Documents/Android/test.jks`
2. Copy your jks file name and put in the end of line number 3

   **Ex:** `text.jks`
3. Open your terminal and enter this command **keytool -list -v -keystore "keystorepath" -alias "keyalias"**

   **Ex:** keytool -list -v -keystore     **/Users/dharm/Documents/Android/test.jks** -alias **test**
4. When you will press enter it will ask for **Enter keystore password**. So please enter your key store password.
5. If you do all the steps successfully then you will get entire information of this certificate(key store).

   **Ex:**

   **MD5:**  D2:52:A1:7C:14:9F:D5:DD:64:35:E2:3F:74:CA:C5:E7

   **SHA1:** D3:32:AA:09:81:71:50:D2:47:20:43:B2:13:A2:D5:55:4B:A7:DC:3C

   **SHA256:** 
   27:8A:84:C5:C3:CE:98:47:A7:73:E2:87:91:5E:5A:A2:F4:B8:D4:D4:0E
6. Now you can put this SHA1 key on google console( `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint`).

Hope it will help you.

**For Video Kindly have a look on it**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g75cZXjmuj8&feature=youtu.be